# Bootstrap full carousel unwanted margins

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I can't figure out why I can't get rid of the white margins on my carousel. I would like to have the carousel's pictures fill the whole space from left to right.

Could you tell me how to correct my code please?

```
 body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   font-family: arial;
   font-size: 18px;
 }
 .carousel .item {
   width: 100%;
   /*slider width */
 }
 .carousel .item img {
   width: 100%;
   /*img width*/
 }
 .container {
   width: 100%;
 }

  <div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img id="beach" src="images/beach.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="images/mountain.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="images/island.jpg">
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this the full code or have you wrapped this inside any other element?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have used Bootstrap's grid correctly. A container with a row and no column will leave zero padding.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/5btL0jps/)**

Your browser's document inspector would quickly show you what element(s) are causing issues like this.

Comment: <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img id="beach"src="images/beach.jpg">
                    </div>
            
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="images/mountain.jpg">
                    </div>
            
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="images/island.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>

Comment: Make sure you're using `container-fluid` and not `container`.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra closing  tag after your last image item. And you should employ the other aspects already mentioned in this post as far using `container` (or `container-fluid`), `row` then `carousel` for your hierarchy.

```
  <div class="item">
     <img src="images/island.jpg">
  </div>
</div> <!--/INNER CAROUSEL CLOSE-->
</div> <!--REMOVE ME! IM ONE TOO MANY-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this example code you are using, the answer lies within the javascript that comes with it, it is set to fullscreen height. If you are using banner images it will appear that there is large margins.